# Правильное формирование json-стринга kotlin

Tags: json, строки, kotlin

Мне нужно сделать такую строку:

```
{"chat": {"a": "get_history"}}
```

пробовал делать так:

```
val getHistory = JSONStringer().`object`().key("chat")
.value(JSONStringer().`object`().key("a").value("get_history").endObject().toString().replace("\'", "")).endObject().toString()
```

пробовал и так:

```
val jsonFormattedString = JSONTokener(jsonObject.toString()).nextValue().toString()
val jsonObject2 = JsonObject()
jsonObject2.addProperty("chat", jsonFormattedString)
```

по итогу получается постоянно такое:

```
{"chat":"{\"a\":\"get_history\"}"}
```

хотя эта часть получается:

```
{"a":"get_history"}
```

Пробовал убрать таким образом `.replace("\\\'", "")` в итоге ничего не получается. Как можно достичь того варианта что нужен изначально?

### UPDATE

Самый худо-бедно работающий вариант:

```
val testValue: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
testValue["chat"] = JSONStringer().`object`().key("a").value("get_history").endObject().toString()
```

и дальше стринг получать так:

```
testValue.toString().replace("=",":")
```

Может у кого будут какие замечания)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все мои варианты были конечно хороши, но они требовали очень много телодвижений. Например нужно было после формирования json и перегонки в стринг еще убирать какие-то символы. Это сложно и не очень правильно. Поэтому в итоге я сделал так:

```
JSONObject(mapOf(
                "chat" to mapOf(
                        "a" to "get_history")).toString()
```

и как результат мы получаем адекватный jsonстринг.